# How much does a IPtables router slow down a connection?

Tags: networking, gateway, latency

I would like to know if introducing a new gateway in my network will slow things down. The question may sound unclear but here is an illustration:

Before Installing gateway server

```
Main Router <=> switches <=>  servers
```

after installing gateway Server

```
Main Router <=> IPtables router <=> switches <=>  servers
```

My question is. How much will this delay incoming outgoing requests / file transfers.
thanks,
RayQuang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the box has enough CPU/memory/bandwidth, nothing at all; almost every modern computer couldn't care less about handling routing for a 100 MBit network, unless you really throw in lots and lots of rules.

Comment: +1. It'll be negligible.

Comment: The only time I've seen an P4 iptables box with 1G of RAM not able to handle the load was when there was 600Mb/s+ of UDP DDOS packets coming at it. With normal traffic usage there will be no issues, even with 3K+ fairly basic rules with no natting.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a low amount of slow-down simply due to the extra processing needed to take the packets from one interface of your IPTables router to the other. There will also be some slow-down that would depend on the exact iptables config you are using (the tables are processed in sequence, each step taking a few machine instructions, generally taking mor time the more you're looking at).

However, we're talking "probably sub-millisecond" delays, so in normal operation, you're unlikely to notice much.

Answer (score 1):

What do you intend to do with iptables? If you are using QUEUE rules, taking the packets into user-space and mangling them then re-injecting them, it will take a long time.

99% of the time it will be basically undetectable.